# Jquery Cycle a secondary animation in a slide doesn't work unless it's the first slide

Tags: jquery, animation, cycle

The goal for my project was to make a slideshow of images, with a dropdown at the top of each of them just using .animate. However, this only works on the first slide, On the rest they don't seem to work whatsoever. Each slide is a div, and inside that div is the div #panel.

```
var $panel = $('#panel');
var $up = $("#up");
var $down = $("#down");

// up arrow
$up.click(function () { 
    $panel.animate({
        top: '-180px',
    }, 500);
    $(this).fadeOut(250);
    $down.fadeIn(250);
    return false;
});

// down arrow
$down.click(function () { 
    $panel.animate({
        top: '0',
    }, 500);
    $(this).fadeOut(250);
    $up.fadeIn(250);        
    return false;
});
```

Oh and the cycle code:

```
$('#base').cycle({
    fx:'scrollHorz',
    prev:   '#prev',
    next:   '#next',
    timeout: 0,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it, it seems like you are using the same IDs for each drops down element. Each element should have its own unique ID. Try using classes for each element instead such as:

```
var panel = $('.panel');
var up = $('.up');
var down = $('.down');
```

Comment: You've saved my life and quite possibly my sleep schedule. Worked perfectly. Almost perfectly, the arrow image won't reposition itself if it's not in the slide that is fired in. A problem for another day! I can sleep now! Seriously thank you.